# UTF8 breaking down, when trying to convert data to json in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have properly configured encoding in my MySQL database as UTF-8. I am receiving data from database without any problem, then I am displaying it in my controller

```
def index
   @languages = Language.all
   render text: @languages[0].name
end
```

Rails is returning me correctly string "ąźaxza" with expected UTF-8 encoding, but when it comes to return data as json it crashes.

```
def index
   @languages = Language.all
   render json: @languages
end
```

It returns json with strings

```
{"languages":[{"languages":{"id":1,"country":"������a","name":"����axza","domain":null,"code":null,"engine_id":null,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}}]}
```

**What can be a problem?**

@languages.inspect is returning

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Language id: 1, country: "\xC4\x85\xC5\x9B\xC5\x82a", name: "\xC4\x85\xC5\xBAaxza", domain: nil, code: nil, engine_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>
```

In database.yml I have set

```
encoding: utf8
collation: utf8_unicode_ci
```

Query "show variables like 'char%';" is returning

```
character_set_client       utf8
character_set_connection   utf8
character_set_database     utf8
character_set_filesystem   binary
character_set_results      utf8
character_set_server       utf8
character_set_system       utf8
```

and query "show variables like 'collation%';" is returning

```
collation_connection    utf8_general_ci
collation_database  utf8_unicode_ci
collation_server    utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it crashes'? What happens exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use gem mysql2 instead of mysql. If anyone has the same problem don't forget to change adapter in database.yml file.